# How to delete a specific file inside a nested folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, file, node.js-fs

I have been trying to delete a specific file in a nested directory.

```
import Express from 'express';
import { baseURL } from '..';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { GuestFile } from '../models/guest-file';

export const GuestDelete = async (request: Express.Request, response: Express.Response) => {
const { identifier } = request.params;

const find_file = await GuestFile.findOne({ identifier });

if (!find_file) {
return response.status(404).json({ error: 'File not found', success: false });
}

const local_file_path = find_file.file_url?.split(`${baseURL}`).pop();
const file_name = local_file_path?.split('/')?.splice(-1)[0];

// Here is where the problem is *********
fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname + `/uploads/${find_file.type}s/`)).find((file) =>      console.log(file));

console.log('file_name', file_name);

response.status(204).json({ success: true, identifier });
};

// deleteFileAfterDelay();
```

`

So I'm trying first to delete the file from the database, then delete it locally from uploads, and as you can see in the image, the uploads folder has a subdirectory. I wanted to be able to map through all the files in the subdirectory, and if the `file_name` matches with the `file` then I `fs.unlinkSyn`, but keep getting errors. Then the path ends up being this     `C:\\Users\\essel_r\\Desktop\\everfile\\backend_api\\\src\\controllers\\uploads\\images\\`

This is what the directory looks like:
[Image of the directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TpIp.png)

I tried using the `fs.unlinkSyn()` and it didn't work:
`fs.readdirSync('/uploads/${find_file.type}/').find((file) => file === file_name &&    fs.unlinkSync(file_name));`
I also tried using the `fs.access()` to check if the file exists, but that too didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot last night and this morning, this is how i did it, so I'll be explaining it well.

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

const directory = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'uploads', 'images')
const file_to_delete = '1676410030129-screen.webp'
```

the **src,** **uploads,** and **images** are nested directories in my folder structure.

```
src
 -index.ts
 -controllers
 -models
 _uploads
    -images
      -1676410030129-screen.webp
    -audio
    -videos
```

Code:

```
fs.readdir(f, (error, files) => {
if (error) throw new Error('Could not read directory');

files.forEach((file) => {
const file_path = path.join(f, file);
console.log(file_path);

fs.stat(file_path, (error, stat) => {
  if (error) throw new Error('File do not exist');
  
  if(stat.isDirectory()){
    console.log('The file is actually a directory')
  }else if (file === file_to_delete ) {
    fs.unlink(file_path, (error)=> {
      if (error) throw new Error('Could not delete file');
        console.log(`Deleted ${file_path}`);
    })
  }

    });
   });
  });
```

**Explanation:**
we first read the directory of the files we want, then if we encounter an error, when we throw the error,or we get the files, which is an array.
we grab each file then join the directory to the file, so we get something like this "`C:\Users\..\Desktop\..\..\src\uploads\images\1676410030129-screen.webp`"
Then we use `fs.stat` to check if the path to the file exists. So if the file doesn't exist we throw an error, or we also check if the path to the actual file is a directory `stat.isDirectory()` if true, we `console.log('The file is actually a directory)`, if it is false, then we move to the next line of the code, and check if the file is which `C:\User\..\1676410030129-screen.webp` is strictly equal to the **`file_to_delete`**  then we delete the file, else we throw another error.

**Whole Code:** index.ts

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

const directory = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'uploads', 'images')
const file_to_delete = '1676410030129-screen.webp'


fs.readdir(f, (error, files) => {
if (error) throw new Error('Could not read directory');

files.forEach((file) => {
const file_path = path.join(f, file);
console.log(file_path);

fs.stat(file_path, (error, stat) => {
if (error) throw new Error('File do not exist');

if(stat.isDirectory()){
console.log('The file is actually a directory')
}else if (file === file_to_delete ) {
fs.unlink(file_path, (error)=> {
  if (error) throw new Error('Could not delete file');
    console.log(`Deleted ${file_path}`);
 })
 }

  });
 });
});
```

For more [Info](https://esselr.vercel.app/thoughts/how-to-delete-a-specific-file-inside-a-nested-folder)

Answer (score 0):

I try to run your code. I change 'import fs from 'fs' => 'const fs = require('fs')' and 'import path from 'path' => 'const path = require('path')'

And in my case, it works well.

```
//import fs from 'fs';
const fs = require('fs')
// import path from 'path';
const path = require('path')

fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname + `/uploads/subDir`)).find((file) =>
  console.log(file)
);
```